# Selenium java - jquery not supported

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, testing, automated-tests

When I click on a button it's supposed to execute a javascript funciton but 
I get this exception .

```
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined.
```

This is the function:

```
function selectAll(){
    $(".role option").attr("selected","selected");
}
```

I am using selenium-java-2.49.1 and htmlunit for my test.

My question is how do I get selenium to recognize jquery?

I cannot modify the javascript function and if I click on the button manually, it works fine.

Comment: you don't need jquery, you can use javascript for the same purpose

Comment: @Edwin I am not allowed to change the function for this.

Comment: It works if you try to click the button manually?

Comment: @StriterAlfa Yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details. If you side is public available please show your code to give us a chance to verify / understand your problem.

In general: HtmlUnit supports jQuery, the whole jQuery test suite is part of the HtmlUnit test suite.

You are using an old selenium/htmlunit version. Please try with the latest one and report your results.

Regarding
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
This is not a dirty attempt, setting this to false is the way every real browser i know works. Because the main focus of HtmlUnit is to support testers and in the end support peoples building web application that behave well this option is true per default to find the errors as early as possible.

And finally.
Yes, HtmlUnit does not support all js features available in modern browsers today. But we try to improve this with every release. If you have issues please open a ticket and we try our best to make an improved version available.